# mumamo-alt-php-tags-mode by default

Tags: php, html, emacs

I just started playing about with emacs yesterday for a project I'm working on. Anyway, i've started using the nxhtml-mumamo for web dev work and have got everything working alright except for when an HTML attribute contains is written as such...

```
<element attribute="<?= _ID ?>"></element>
```

... which invalidates the source.
I've found that enabling mumamo-alt-php-tags-mode sorts this problem, and now I'm looking at how to automatically execute this whenever a .php / .html file is opened. I know that this is done through my ~/.emacs file, however as I'm already executing nxhtml-mumamo when opening this file I'm not sure how to run another function.

Any help?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(add-hook 'nxhtml-mumamo-mode-hook (lambda () (mumamo-alt-php-tags-mode 1)))
```

This will cause all buffers in `nxhtml-mumamo-mode` to also be in the `mumamo-alt-php-tags-mode`, if you want to restrict it to just `.html` and `.php` buffers, you'd add something a little more involved like this:

```
(add-hook 'nxhtml-mumamo-mode-hook 'enable-alt-tags-in-certain-files)
(defun enable-alt-tags-in-certain-files ()
  "enable mumamo-alt-php-tags-mode in .php and .html files"
  (when (string-match "\\.php$\\|\\.html\\$" (buffer-file-name))
    (mumamo-alt-php-tags-mode 1)))
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. 

I'm going to go with the first for now as it's exactly what I'm looking for, but thanks for the extended version.

I'd upvote if I could, but I'm still a newbie.

Comment: Even without the minimal reputation for upvoting, you can accept answers to questions you've asked.